# How do I reset the terminal directory VS code runs on when pressing the f5 key?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am learning to program on java using VS code and the terminal directory when I press f5 to run and debug a program is of a different file to the current file. When i use the "Run Java" button on the top right, it runs in the correct directory. How do I make it so that pressing f5 to run and debug will use the directory of the current program.

Directory when pressing f5:

`part04-Part04_24.PrintingAFile %`

Expected directory and directory when using the "Run Java" button:

`part04-Part04_26.GuestListFromAFile`

I have ticked the "Clear before reusing" option but that doesn't change the directory f5 uses

With a launch.json:

`{

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Current File",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
    }
]
```

}`

located within my workspace at "/Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/moocfi.test-my-code/workspaces/.tmc/.vscode/launch.json" terminal reads as:

`.tmc%`

and is unable to read any files in my exercises when i press f5.

Without that launch.json file, pressing f5 will set the directory to the exercise I first run and when changing exercises, pressing f5 will make the new exercise run in the already set directory, even after the closing the old exercise and killing terminal. The only way it resets is by relaunching vscode enitrely.

Comment: does the java launch config have a `cwd` property, if so set it to the text: `"${fileDirname}"`

Comment: Hi rio, I realised I don't have a launch.json file set up yet, should each of my folders have their own launch config or the main workspace? The launch config for the main workspace is currently blank and when I added the cwd property with the text, it doesn't do anything

Comment: Showcase your catalog structure. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: if you don't us the content of your `.vscode/launch.json` we are in the dark

Comment: Please edit your post to add details rather than in the comments section.

Comment: If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.
If your problem has been solved, please close the thread。